# added javascript property to window object loses value

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
var wins = [];

function openWin(index, val) {
    wins[index] = window.open(...);
    wins[index].prop1 = val;         // add a custom property
    console.log(wins[index].prop1);  // prop1 is true here
}

function checkProp1(index) {
    // wins[index] is still a valid object but prop1 is undefined
    console.log(wins[index].prop1);
}

openWin(0, true);
checkProp1(0);
```

Why does "prop1" lose its value as soon as openWin() exists?
How do I make the associated properties maintain their values?

Comment: are you working cross origin?

Comment: There's no obvious reason why `prop1` would be defined in the first `console.log()` but not the second. Returning from the first function and calling the second shouldn't have any effect on that. If it were a cross-site issue I would expect both `console.log()` calls to exhibit the same behavior. Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It will also be a case if popup is blocked by browser and doesn't open from say click event. So the question is, doesn't window actually open or it is blocked?

Comment: If there is a problem of that nature, I would still expect both `console.log()` calls to show the same result. Returning from the `openWin()` function and immediately calling the `checkProp1()` function is really the same thing as just putting two `console.log()` calls in a row. If one fails, both should. Of course there may be something I've overlooked! @Perry, have you tried just putting a second `console.log()` call inside `openWin()` to see what happens?

Comment: No its not cross origin.

Comment: The popup is not being blocked. A window reference is being returned every time.

Answer (score 1):

The [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) returns either the handle to the window, or null in case the popup didn't work. It might be easier to store the windows as a property of another object and add it to your cache like that.

To do so, you could do it in the following form

```js
;
(function(ns) {
  ns.windowHandler = ns.windowHandler || {
    add: function(index, val) {
      var windowHandle = window.open(index, val),
        obj = {
          handle: windowHandle,
          prop1: index
        };
      if (typeof ns.windowHandler.windows === 'undefined') {
        ns.windowHandler.windows = [];
      }
      ns.windowHandler.windows.slice(index, 0, [obj]);
    },
    checkProp: function(index) {
      if (typeof ns.windowHandler.windows === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }
      return ns.windowHandler.windows[index].prop1;
    }
  }:
}(window));

window.windowHandler.add(0, true);
console.log(window.windowHandler.checkProp(0));
```

A fiddle you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/hdtdcp2u/)

Comment: I tried this approach before posting and it does indeed work but not as elegant as just adding a property to the window object. I was curious if someone can explain why the property in my code above is lost though. Need an answer to that more than an alternative workaround.

Comment: @Perry I have to say, i tested your code directly yesterday, and I got twice true as an output, so in my case, i couldn't verify your original assumption, for me it was working. Maybe you could include with which browser(s) you were testing it? (I tested with Firefox Developer Edition). Your question about elegance, is IMO, subjective. Can you say for sure what will happen in the future to the windowreference, or that you will always be allowed to update/change something on the object, you are eventually wrapping an extra functionality, it only seems logical to wrap the values

Comment: Yea, you may have a point. I could't even get it working in fiddle. The code craps out when I add the property to the window object and the code stops there. http://jsfiddle.net/p7huv319/ I have tried this code in all major browsers: IE11, and latest Chrome and Firefox. They all exibit this problem so I don't understand why you don't see it. Did you use the exact code I have above?